# MVC4 Razor Page not showing content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to MVC4 and Razor syntax. I apologize upfront if this is too simple a question, I haven't been able to find the answer searching...

I am wanting to do something along the lines of the following...

**Sample 1**

```
@if (Model.UserDoesNotHaveAccess)
{
    <h1>You do not have access</h1>
    Response.End();
}

<h1> You do have access </h1>
```

When I run the page with sample 1 code I get a blank page if UserDoesNotHaveAccess is true - nothing is rendered. When I run the page with sample 2 code however it works... I do not want to have to nest everything in an if else statement like I have done in sample 2. Is there an easy way to get something similar to sample 1 working?

**Sample 2**

```
@if (Model.UserDoesNotHaveAccess)
{
    <h1>You do not have access</h1>    
}
else
{
    <h1> You do have access </h1>
}
```

Comment: Normally you would redirect to another Action/View in the Action if the user doesn't have access to that page. Or you can use the Authorize attribute to handle this. I don't think you want this kind of logic in the view.

Comment: Thanks, I think we will do a redirect since it is a legacy application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to restrict access decorate the controller action with `[Authorize]`
They will be redirected to the login page

If you are using roles you can also specify which role has access like

`[Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]`

Then anyone not in that role would be redirected to login as well.